# Настройка автоматической заливки c github

Tags: git, github

Добрый день. Имеется на сервере репозиторий с проектом, я его запушил на github.com. Вопрос в следующем, если я изменю код на github  и нажму commit, как настроить автоматическую заливку нового кода(версии) в мой репозиторий на сервер?
Использую aws ec2

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/ru/blogs/devops/automatically-deploy-from-github-using-aws-codedeploy/

Comment: @tcpack4 мои попытки настроить по инструкции увенчались неудачей. После начала деплоя мне выдало failed. Система получается должна переписывать полностью инстанс? Зачем такая избыточность, если мне нужно просто поменять файл грубо говоря автоматом с удаленного репозитория.

Comment: нет конечно, автодейплой не будет перезаписывать инстанс. Без логов я не могу ничего сказать. Amazon CodeDeploy их сервис и скажем родной для их экосистемы, но можно его не использовать. А взять jenkins - одна из распространенных систем CI, мануалов множество. Если не хотите настраивать все это, то проще перейти на beanstalk, там через интерфейс можно сделать автодеплой за 5 мин через SFTP с логами, посткомандами и прочим.